# LINQ - Is there a way to get element values after grouping without ForEach?

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreach, grouping

I have an Items table that contains a CategoryId field.  This is an FK into a Categories table.  I want to group my Items by CategoryId and return the Items and Categories.Name.

I know I can do this in C#:

```
var ItemsByCat = 
    from i in Items
    group i by i.CategoryId into g
    select g

foreach(var n in ItemsByCat)
{
    blah, blah
}
```

My question is - is there a way to get at the element values part of the grouping without having to iterate through with a loop?  Something like:

```
from i in Items
group i by i.CategoryId into g
select new {
    CategoryID = g.Key,
    CategoryName = ???,
    Items = ???
}
```

Many thanks,

BK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
from i in Items
group i by i.CategoryId into g
select new 
{
    CategoryID = g.Key,
    CategoryName = g.First().Category.Name,
    Items = g
}
```

EDIT: I hope this answers your question from the comments.

`g` is a collection of Items grouped by their `CategoryId`. `Items` in the `select` can be a projection including whatever subset of `Item` properties you require. Example:

```
from i in Items
group i by i.CategoryId into g
select new 
{
    CategoryID = g.Key,
    CategoryName = g.First().Category.Name,
    Items = g.Select(a => new{a.ItemID, a.ItemName})
}
```

Comment: Ah, I get it - so g is a collection and by using .First() I can just grab the CategoryName.  Many Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. g is just another type of collection that implements `IEnumerable`. I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: One last question - what if the Items in the select was a collection of objects with Items.ItemID, Items.Name?  In other words, I don't want to return a collection of entire Items records, just a subset of the Items fields.

Comment: I added some info to my answer that I think answer your question. Let me know.

Comment: Straight on perfect!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What about joining the Categories table?

```
from i in Items
join c in Categories on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
group i by i.CategoryId into g
select new {
    CategoryID = g.Key,
    CategoryName = c.Name,
    Items = i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CategoryName` should be `i.Category.CategoryName //the name property`

given you have the relationship setup properly.

The items should be the values of group by, not sure why you'd need to do it again.

Comment: After the grouping, i is no longer in scope.  All I have to work with is g.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, the values of each item in g is your grouped by items. Each grouped entry has a Key and Items(which is your items, lol)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a collection of Categories in a variable categories it would look like this:

```
var ItemsByCategory = 
  from i in items
  join c in categories on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
  group i by i.CategoryId into g
  select new {
    CategoryId=g.Key,
    CategoryName=c.Name,
    Items=g.Items
}
```

Comment: This is assuming you're not using Entity Framework. In EF you just walk your navigation properties no joins necessary.

Comment: I think c is out of scope once I do the grouping.  If I move the join below the grouping and join to categories on c.CategoryId = g.Key it seems to work.  Is this a good approach?

Comment: That is fine...I find it odd that it doesn't work the other way though but it might be the way it's getting parsed.